# How can I customize Java Date Format

Tags: java

From the java doc, the MEDIUM format is: 
MEDIUM is longer, such as Jan 12, 1952

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html

How can I customize it so that I does not display the year? And spell out "Jan" to January?

Do I need to do that myself?
* chop off the string after the ','
* have a table which map the month short name (Jan) to its long name (January)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
// For months like "Jan"
String formatted = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd").format(new Date());

// For months like "January"
String formatted = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd").format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the possibility of using `SimpleDateFormat`, there also exists `DateTimeFormatter`.

I think that `DateTimeFormatter` is the better option, because

- It was introduced more recently (Java 8)
- It is thread-save

One example:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime; 
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;  

public class Time {    
  public static void main(String[] args) {    
   LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.now();

   DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd. MMM");
   String timeDate = time.format(formatter);
   System.out.println(timeDate);  
  }    
}
```

This will produce something like `30. May` as output.

More information can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) and [there](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-).